# how to retrieve specific data from multicolumn list view in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using multicolumn List View in android application. I am storing data in different text view using Simple Adapter. Now I want to retrieve data from list view, i.e every specific row and column. I am adding row to Listview dynamically.
This is how I am storing.

```
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;
        s2=new String[s1.length];
        for(int i=0;i<s2.length;i++)
        {
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("name",s1[i][0]);
            map.put("salary",s1[i][1]);
            map.put("age",s1[i][2]);
            map.put("exp",s1[i][3]);
            map.put("invest",s1[i][4]);
            map.put("gain",s1[i][5]);
            mylist.add(map);

    }
sd =new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mylist,R.layout.activity_listview,new 
    String[]{"name","iprice","qty","total","lprice","gain"},new int[]
    {R.id.t1,R.id.t2,R.id.t3,R.id.t4,R.id.t5,R.id.t6});
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        }
```

custom XML File code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="4dip"
android:paddingBottom="6dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/t1"
android:layout_width="70dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="text1"/>
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/t2"
  android:layout_width="30dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="text2" />
  <TextView 
  android:id="@+id/t3"
  android:layout_width="20dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="text3" />
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/t4"
  android:layout_width="55dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="text4" />
  <TextView 
  android:id="@+id/t5"
  android:layout_width="30dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="text5" />
  <TextView 
  android:id="@+id/t6"
  android:layout_width="30dip"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:text="text6" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

main XML :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="288dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1" >
 </ListView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Now on click on specific row I wanted to retrieve name and age field from listview.How can I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get from your `arraylist` on `ListView` item click. Like below,

```
 String name = mylist.get(position).get("name");
 String age = mylist.get(position).get("age");
```

And after that you want to set this string's in `TextView` then you can use this

```
 textName.setText(name);
 textAge.setText(age);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1)).getText().toString();
            String age = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv3)).getText().toString();


            TextView tv111 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            tv111.setText(name);

            TextView tv222 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tw);
            tv222.setText(age);
        }
    });
```

and in main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="text1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="text3" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: no its not working..and onItemClick method is added once again

Comment: its working in my case...can you post your activity code here

Comment: I am not sending data to another activity as i wanted to display it in this activity only.

Comment: in this activity where you want to display data when click on any item....(in dialog box or other)

Answer (score 0):

add itemclicklistener to the listview and get the clicked view , and then its child

```
thelistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentvu, View clickedvu, final int ind,long arg3) 
            {
                ///
                     TextView text_view1=(TextView)((View)clickedvu.getElementById(R.id.t1));
                     TextView text_view2=(TextView)((View)clickedvu.getElementById(R.id.t2));
                     TextView text_view3=(TextView)((View)clickedvu.getElementById(R.id.t3));
                     TextView text_view4=(TextView)((View)clickedvu.getElementById(R.id.t4));
                     TextView text_view5=(TextView)((View)clickedvu.getElementById(R.id.t5));
                     TextView text_view6=(TextView)((View)clickedvu.getElementById(R.id.t6));
            }

        });
```

Hope this helps
**EDIT:**
clickedvu here according to the documentation return the view which was clicked/touched, so we should be able to get the elements inside it

Comment: The method getElementById() is undefined for the type View